# Loading more rows in the tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to load 15 records initially and then when the user clicks on the show more row of the cell, i need to load the next 20 or available records in my tableview. I am looking at this question posted in SO.

This functionality can be seen in appStore too. Where you load the next number of records.

Here the solution is;

```
`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.numberOfRowsVisible;
}

-(void)moreButtonClickAction {
    if (self.numberOfRowsVisible < self.maxNumberOfRows) 
        self.numberOfRowsVisible = MIN(self.numberOfRowsVisible + 10, self.maxRows);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I initialized and hard coded the value in the viewDidLoad for numberOfRowsVisible as 15.

```
self.numberOfRowsVisible=[NSNumber numberWithInt:15];
```

in `numberOfRowsInSection` - i am not sure if this is correct.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return MIN([self.arrayRecords count], 15);
}
```

in the `moreButtonClickAction`

```
-(void)moreButtonClickAction {
    if (self.numberOfRowsVisible < [self.arrayRecords count]) 
        self.numberOfRowsVisible = MIN(self.numberOfRowsVisible + 15, [self.arrayRecords count]);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This is how i edited my code to suit the above suggestion left in SO. but this is not working. There seems to be some issue with `MIN`. I am not in MAC at the moment, so i can't remember the exact warning/error i got. So could someone kindly help me out.

Comment: `self.arrayRecords` contains all the records, example like a 1000 of records, and i will have to display only 15 at a time using this array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Don't use an NSNumber object, a plain integer will do.
2) Why not just have an integer variable that shows the current number of rows that you want to display, and initialize with 15, and keep it in your class instance.
3) You don't even have to use MIN:

```
return [self.arrayRecords count] < self.numberOfRowsVisible ? [self.arrayRecords count] : self.numberOfRowsVisible;
```

Comment: Then what might be the `moreButtonClickAction ` method look like ?

Comment: If numberOfRowsVisible is an integer type, then you can use what you have.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use MAX instead of MIN if you want to show all possible entries.

Comment: self.numberOfRowsVisible is a NSNumber. So can i use this inside MIN or MAX ?

Comment: MAX needs Integers you can cast it with intValue. Just chain it

Comment: You need to change that to just plain integer.  You don't need to use an NSNumber in this code, and if you do elsewhere, you can convert it there.  An NSNumber is a number object, not just a number.

Answer (score 1):

numberOfRowsInSection should return an integer.
self.numberOfRowsVisible is not an integer.

viewDidLoad:

```
self.numberOfRowsVisible=15;
```

main implementation:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.numberOfRowsVisible;
}

-(void)moreButtonClickAction {
    if (self.numberOfRowsVisible < [self.arrayRecords count]) {
        self.numberOfRowsVisible += 15;
        if (self.numberOfRowsVisible > [self.arrayRecords count]) {
            self.numberOfRowsVisible = [self.arrayRecords count];
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

off the top of my head, code could do with re-factoring.

Comment: What will hapen if we have a8 records. Initially we will load 15 records, and the next time we will have to load 3 records. But if we return `self.numberOfRowsVisible` we will get an error. How could we fix it ?

Comment: The code above starts off with 15. Adds another 15, detects that it is higher than 18 (max count) and so reduces it to 18. There is nothing to fix.